# How can you measure angle degrees in nature?

Tags: trigonometry

I am right now learning trigonometry and I wanted to know how can we calculate angle degrees in real life? I have seen an example in one of my book where you had to calculate the height of a tree with the radius * radian (as in the Arc Length Formula).

My question here is : Is there any instrument we should use or is there a way to approximately calculate the angle degrees from our view (eyes) to the highest point of a tree?

Comment: This is essentially what a [sextant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextant) (and its relatives) is used for. There are also other less precise instruments available, which are essentially protractors with addenda.

Comment: The link shows how to construct a simple instrument called a clinometer: https://nrich.maths.org/5382

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much